# How to highlight intersection of meshes?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, volumetrics

I am making an animation of a molecule.
How can I highlight the intersection of spheres as shown in the below animation???

I tried volumes, but it is not showing the intersection prominent like this.
(Can we do it with Boolean)

Thank you so much in advance. :)

[image]

Comment: Sure you can use boolean. Just duplicate the model and copy the transforms of the original with a copy transforms consraint. Add a boolean modifier and choose an other material for it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, booleans can be used here. It should be noted that booleans can be rather glitchy in many cases. There are ways to mitigate them, but the methods I know of won't apply very well to the type of animation you're looking for.

Create a large cube that encompasses all of your objects. Then, apply two *Intersect Boolean* modifiers, one for each of the intersecting objects.

The first boolean will cutout the cube into something that resembles one of your objects (I say resembles simply due to the glitchy nature of booleans), and the second intersect will take the cube (that now is one of your objects), and cuts out whatever is not touching the second.

Here's a quick demo of that:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Just to clarify, We  have 3 objects here, 2 spheres and 1 cube. what will be the exact order of modifiers to be added on the objects with which objects.

Comment: The order doesn't actually matter. This solution is essentially the same as FFeller's comment on your question, except instead of duplicating one of the intersecting objects and applying the the boolean modifier to that, I'm creating an all encompassing cube and using the first boolean modifier to transform the cube into one of your objects. Now since the cube is one of your objects, the intersection between that and the other object is the area you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This might point the way to a Cycles Shader approach.

[image]

- The 'Transparent' cluster sets up a transparent material with no refraction, but some gloss on the surface, which does not cast shadows.
- The 'Inside' cluster returns 1 if the number of transparent surfaces a ray has passed through is odd. i.e. The shading point is 'inside' a transparent solid
- ... But we don't want to catch the backfacing faces of the transparent solid itself.

[image]

I can't immediately think of a simple way to set up the gradated 'alarm' colors.. but if this way isn't suitable for some other reason....

Comment: Genius! it worked!!!